# Buttons for iPhone App. How?

Tags: iphone

We are building an flashcard iPhone App with a developer. 
Here are the screens: http://cobocards.com/blog/2009/09/iphone-app-geplant/lang/en/

Which images do I need to give the developer for buidling the app?
- A Button in two states?
- The Navigation Bar just in 1px for the background?
- The immage for the button with the text or without the text in it?

What would help me is a sample package of an App with all the images, so I can have a look wha is needed

Comment: Perhaps ask the developer what assets he needs? He should be able to tell you. If not, why is he/she developing your app?

Comment: I'll do that. But it would also be helpfull if somebody would provide me some kind of answer I can work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your buttons require two button states, a normal and a highlighted state. That includes your "Download" "Flip Through" and "Study" buttons.
As for your buttons don't bake the text onto the image, let the developer put the image in the program, as  this will help you later to localize your application.

The Navigation Bar's buttons can be created programatically, no need to create them in images.

The Navigation Bar's background can be set programatically, no need for a 1px file to make it black.

The Toolbar at the bottom containing Download can be drawn quite easily programatically, no need for an image there.

Your checkboxes also need the unselected and selected states.

The CoboCard at the top requires a png 24-bit with transparency. It'll have to be sized less than 44px, but since the bar at the top is 44px, perhaps resize it down to 32-36px tall.

I hope this helps. Although it really should be your developer asking you for these assets as they're pretty typical things.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the kind of answer I was waiting for :) 100 points for you.